# Debug.Assert() has stopped working in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, assert

For some reason, the following line does nothing in my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
```

I have triple-checked that I am using the Debug configuration and "Define Debug constant" is checked in the Debug configuration settings.

The same problem also occurs in my unit test project.

Implementing my own assert method seems trivial, but a bit awkward. Any hints on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I am using several third-party modules in my project. Could this perhaps be caused by referencing a module which is compiled in release mode?

Comment: Have you double checked you're not running the release version?

Comment: How about open your dll/exe with Reflector and see whether the assert is actually in the code? And is your assembly actually loaded from the location you think it is? Maybe check another time that you are using the debug version.

Comment: @ChrisF: As I said, yes. Three times... :-)

Comment: Are you sure the assembly that has `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);` is loaded?

Comment: Heres something to try: Use Resharper instead of VS to run the tests using Debug and make sure the line is actually hit. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: Is this in a controller? A view? They're compiled separately, with different options.

Comment: @Yuriy: I already tried that. The line is definitely hit. But there is no Assertion Exception. Also, the problem also happens when I am running the actual website on my debug webserver, so it does not seem to be related to unit testing at all.

Comment: @Craig: I tried this is both in a test method in my unit testing project and in an action method in my controller.

Comment: It is TraceListener.Fail() that displays the assertion.  Which trace listeners are active is subject to configuration.  Check the docs for DefaultTraceListener for details.  And verify the AssertUiEnabled property.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.Net Assertion are displayed in the VS Console while your webpage is displayed through VisualStudio. It doesn't interrupt the thread to display a MsgBox or break to the assertion line like a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Ancient question but if you don't have a default listener defined it will not display a message dialog as per usual. I haven't confirmed whether it actually fires and just gets eaten (I suspect this is case) or whether it just doesn't fire at all.

But either way it will not show the dialog.

From the docs for [DefaultTraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The display of the message box for Assert and Fail method calls
>   depends on the presence of the DefaultTraceListener. If the
>   DefaultTraceListener is not in the Listeners collection, the message
>   box is not displayed.
>
> The DefaultTraceListener can be removed by the
>    element, by the  element, or by calling the Clear
>   method on the Listeners property
>   (System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear()).

You can check your listeners and get the type by using some code like below:

```
 var listeners = new TraceListener[Debug.Listeners.Count];
 Debug.Listeners.CopyTo(listeners, 0);
 foreach (var listener in listeners) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Name : {0} of type : {1}", listener.Name, listener.GetType());
 }
```

If you don't have one called "Default", `Debug.Assert` will silently fail.

As far as configuration goes, this WILL work assuming a listener named Default is available:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false">
        <listeners>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This WILL work assuming a listener named Default is available:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false">
        <listeners>
           <add name="bigEarsListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TracingInfo.log"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This WILL work as we explictly define our Default:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false">
        <listeners>
           <remove name="Default" />
           <add name="Default" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
           <add name="bigEarsListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TracingInfo.log"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This WONT work:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false">
        <listeners>
           <remove name="Default" />
           <add name="bigEarsListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TracingInfo.log"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

If you don't have a diagnostics section in your web.config then the Default might be getting removed or overriden by some VS Extension etc, so adding this section should bring it back to expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running through ASP.NET MVC, could there be a debug=false in your web.config that is causing the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have just checked my web.config and the word debug is only in this line: <compilation tempDirectory="r:\\ASP.NET Temp" debug="true" assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspCoverageInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">

Comment: Also look for whether there's a "system.diagnostics" section in the config file. You can turn off assertions in your config file.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the suggestion, but the word "diagnostics" is not mentioned in my web.config.

Comment: @Adrian Grigore have you checked your other configurations for .NET? If you create a simple Console App does it get hit?